# Error : "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values"

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, discussion-board

I am facing this error while creating new discussion reply programmatically. I am using the below lines to create reply

```
SPListItem topic = spListDisc.GetItemById(id);
SPListItem reply = SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply(topic);
reply["Body"] = "Hello";
reply["Author"] = Currentuser;
reply.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Is there anything going wrong?

Comment: i think reply["Author"] = Currentuser is the cause for the issue. remove  that line and try to update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tarun , but that is not the problem, i have checked it.